# Why is implicit conversion from Long to RichLong not applied where a supertype of RichLong is expected?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Scala 2.8 spec says in section 7.3 (highlighting is mine):

> Implicit parameters and methods can also define implicit conversions called views.
>   A view from type S to type T is defined by an implicit value which has function type
>   S=>T or (=>S)=>T or by a method convertible to a value of that type.
>   Views are applied in two situations.
>
> 1. If an expression e is of type T, and T **does not conform** to the expression’s
>      expected type pt. In this case an implicit v is searched which is applicable to
>      e and **whose result type conforms** to pt. The search proceeds as in the case of
>      implicit parameters, where the implicit scope is the one of T => pt. If such a
>      view is found, the expression e is converted to v(e).
>
> [...]

given the above and the following facts:

1. `Long` is not a subtype of `java.lang.Comparable[Long]`, i.e. **does not conform** to type `T` where `T <: java.lang.Comaparable[Long]`
2. `Predef` contains `implicit def longWrapper (x: Long) : RichLong`
3. `RichLong` is a subtype of `java.lang.Comparable[Long]`, i.e. **conforms** to type `T` where `T <: java.lang.Comaparable[Long]`

I would expect the implicit conversion to be applied where `Long` is encountered and a subtype of `java.lang.Comparable[Long]` is expected. However:

```
scala> def test[T <: java.lang.Comparable[Long]](c: T) = println(c)
test: [T <: java.lang.Comparable[Long]](c: T)Unit

scala> test(12L)
<console>:7: error: inferred type arguments [Long] do not conform to method test's type parameter bounds [T <: java.lang
.Comparable[Long]]
       test(12L)
       ^
```

The result is as expected if the value is converted explicitly:

```
scala> test(longWrapper(12L))
12
```

Why isn't the conversion function applied implicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a view-bound (`<%`) to have compiler look for and apply the implicit conversion.

```
scala> def test[T <% java.lang.Comparable[Long]](c: T) = println(c)
test: [T](c: T)(implicit evidence$1: (T) => java.lang.Comparable[Long])Unit

scala> test(12L)
12
```

You can read more about view-bound on [this](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch12.html) page (Ctrl+F for "view bound").